# Why use "was", not "were" in "If I was given more time, I would..."

Tags: word-choice, subjunctive-mood

Is this sentence formal?

> If I **was** given more time, I would have less pressure

Why do we use "I was" rather than "I were"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. You need to include your own research or use the [search box](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=if+were%2C+if+was) when you ask a question here. Please visit Help Center and read the guidelines.

Comment: “We” don't. Some people do; I'm not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

@ darcy ,Happy Saturday

According to below rule

**"Use a singular verb with distances, periods of time, sums of money, etc., when considered as a unit"**

and
**"Basic Rule. A singular subject (she, Bill, car) takes a singular verb (is, goes, shines), whereas a plural subject takes a plural verb."**

So , here for the time we need to use  **"Was"**,instead of **"Were"**

As per below comments , according to  **@KateBunting**,

Those are both grammatical, but mean very different things. 'If I were' is in the **Subjective mood**, 'if I was' is in the **Indicative mood**.

**"If I were"** is It's used in formal and literary English after a limited number of verbs.

**Yes** ,***grammatical strictness indicates that "if I were" is usually correct and should be used.***

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your answer is wrong. Please read the question again.

Comment: "Were" in this case is not a plural verb, but the subjunctive. To be strictly correct, the subjunctive should be used with "if". There are other threads on this topic.

Comment: The modal preterite "was" is a perfectly acceptable alternative to the somewhat formal "were", which, btw, is not a subjunctive form but 'irrealis' mood.